# awk with exclude pattern in shell

Tags: shell, awk, grep

text file has below lines named 'log'

```
--- [n-event-group-3] action
--- [n-event-group-8] action.service
--- [n-event-group-2] essing.service.
--- [n-event-group-10] service.
--- [ost-stats-event] host.
--- 1077916, partition: 10, 
--- [d | vm-cm-event] cm.service.
--- [d | vm-cm-eve] cm.service
error: not found
com.rom.nom
--- [-event-group-11] ervice
--- [-event-group-15] ervice
--- [-event-group-20] ervice
--- [-event-group-99] ervice
--- [-event-group-133] ervice
--- [-event-group-13] ervice
--- [-event-group-13] ervice
--- [-event-group-13] ervice
```

want to grep lines containing `[-event-group-13]` only and all line which does not have pattern `[-event-group-(digits)]`

so result needed is

```
--- [ost-stats-event] host.
--- 1077916, partition: 10, 
--- [d | vm-cm-event] cm.service.
--- [d | vm-cm-eve] cm.service
error: not found
com.rom.nom
--- [-event-group-13] ervice
--- [-event-group-13] ervice
--- [-event-group-13] ervice
--- [-event-group-13] ervice
```

```
awk '!/-event-group-/{print} /-event-group-13/{print}' file gives
```

```
--- [ost-stats-event] host.
--- 1077916, partition: 10, 
--- [d | vm-cm-event] cm.service.
--- [d | vm-cm-eve] cm.service
error: not found
com.rom.nom
--- [-event-group-133] ervice  <- don't print this line
--- [-event-group-13] ervice
--- [-event-group-13] ervice
--- [-event-group-13] ervice
```

Comment: `awk '!/-event-group-/; /\[-event-group-13\]/' file`

Comment: Your expected output doesn't match your stated requirements since `--- [n-event-group-3] action`, for example, "does not have pattern [-event-group-(digits)]".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
awk '!/-event-group-/{print} /-event-group-13]/{print}' file
                                             ^
                                         look here
```

or

```
awk '!/-event-group-/{print} /-event-group-13\y/{print}' file
```

`\y` is *word boundary* for `GNU awk`.

Yields:

```
--- [ost-stats-event] host.
--- 1077916, partition: 10, 
--- [d | vm-cm-event] cm.service.
--- [d | vm-cm-eve] cm.service
error: not found
com.rom.nom
--- [-event-group-13] ervice
--- [-event-group-13] ervice
--- [-event-group-13] ervice
```

Answer (score 1):

You say you want:

> to grep lines containing [-event-group-13] only and

> all line which does not have pattern [-event-group-(digits)]

This does that using any awk:

```
$ awk '/\[-event-group-13]/ || !/\[-event-group-[0-9]+]/' file
--- [n-event-group-3] action
--- [n-event-group-8] action.service
--- [n-event-group-2] essing.service.
--- [n-event-group-10] service.
--- [ost-stats-event] host.
--- 1077916, partition: 10,
--- [d | vm-cm-event] cm.service.
--- [d | vm-cm-eve] cm.service
error: not found
com.rom.nom
--- [-event-group-13] ervice
--- [-event-group-13] ervice
--- [-event-group-13] ervice
```

but maybe this is what you actually want (still using any awk) as it produces the expected output you posted:

```
$ awk '/\[-event-group-13]/ || !/\[[^]]*-event-group-[0-9]+]/' file
--- [ost-stats-event] host.
--- 1077916, partition: 10,
--- [d | vm-cm-event] cm.service.
--- [d | vm-cm-eve] cm.service
error: not found
com.rom.nom
--- [-event-group-13] ervice
--- [-event-group-13] ervice
--- [-event-group-13] ervice
```